# How to factor $\frac{27}{125}a^6b^9-\frac{1}{64}c^{12}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I'm stuck with the following:

$\frac{27}{125}a^6b^9-\frac{1}{64}c^{12}$

My idea was/is the following:

$\frac{3^3a^6b^9}{5^3}-\frac{c^{12}}{8^2}$

Trouble is that I don't know where to go from here. If I go via LCD for $5^3$ and $8^2$ I'll get 8000 in the denominator and high numbers in the numerator, which I think isn't the point here with factorization. Ideally I'd get something like $(3a^3b^3)^2$ in the first numerator but for the whole expression, of course. Maybe I'm looking at it for too long, so I've lost perspective, but usual helping tools like wolfram and symbolab aren't of much help.

Comment: It looks like Wolfram's alternative form isn't the same thing because $\frac{576}{320} \ne \frac{27}{125}$.  But it's not at all clear to me what you are trying to do.  Do you want to simplify this expression somehow?

Comment: I have no idea where wolfram is coming from. Yes, I want to express this difference of squares with multiplication/distribution.

Comment: @crash It must've been my typo or something, because I don't see it: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=27%2F125a%5E6b%5E9-1%2F64c%5E12 I'll edit that out then. Thanks.

Comment: @crash did I? I got confused by my unfortunate typing error on W|A for checking result though :/ Question is still the same, what would be the best approach to factor this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use
$x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$

$\frac{27}{125}a^6b^9-\frac{1}{64}c^{12}
=\left(\frac{3a^2b^3}{5}\right)^3-\left(\frac{c^4}{4}\right)^3$.

Now,
let $x=\frac{3a^2b^3}{5}$
and
$y=\frac{c^4}{4}$
and use that factorization to get
$[\frac{3a^2b^3}{5}-\frac{c^4}{4}][\frac{9a^4b^6}{25}+\frac{3a^2b^3c^4}{20}+\frac{c^8}{16}]$

Comment: I agree, I went too far in helping.  Deleted.  Good answer.

Comment: I haven't noticed it was a difference of cubes. I need more practice! Thank you both for wonderful response!